# In-line Sound Level Meter Circuit (with LED bar).

Tags: sound, led-strip

I am looking to create an in-line sound level meter (indicator). This would connect between the headphone audio out (from a computer) and a pair of headphones. I do not need to get a precise measurement but want the sound level to be indicated on an LED bar. Ideally, I would like the top and bottom levels (the sound level that triggers the brightest green LED) to be configurable (possibly via a variable resistor).

I do have a component in mind for the 10 segment LED display: http://www.maplin.co.uk/10-segment-display-2128

I have already consulted Google - but I was looking for some practical advice.

Answer (score 1):

The LM3915 chip would help you. Look into the datasheet, for instance here http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/8899/NSC/LM3915.html or get a complete schematic here http://www.afiata.com/vu-meter-using-a-lm3915-circuit-diagram/

Comment: See also: LM3914, and any number of existing ready-made devices/products for peanuts from eBay china. The level meter circuit is a staple of almost every electronics hobby book & website ever.

Comment: see also complete project [at Elliot Sound Products](http://sound.westhost.com/project60.htm) and the [complete meter project listing](http://sound.westhost.com/projects-0.htm#mix)